# filling up a depression to create new surface

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, grass-gis, depression-filling

A collegue here has a problem I cannot help with. She has the surface (as raster) of a landslide release area (from AFTER the slide) and wants to calculate the calculate the theoretical/approximate volume of the release surface. Is there a funtion in ArcGIS or GRASS GIS 7 that fills the slide relesease area? The problem is that we do not have the pre-release surface, so cut/fill does not work here.

Comment: Can you identify both the release area and the accumulation area, or do you have just the post-release elevations?  (Showing us an image of the DEM would help.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can perfectly use the stable GRASS GIS 6.4.x (7 is not necessary):

- depression areas can be filled with [r.fill.dir](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.fill.dir.html) (filters and generates a depressionless elevation map and a flow direction map from a given elevation layer)
- and resulting volume can be calculated by [r.volume](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.volume.html) or [r.lake](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.lake.html)

Comment: This most likely is not a depression in the sense of areas that would fill with water.  Even if it were to have such a shape, the amount of fill surely would grossly underestimate the landslide volume, because the fill would level out the depression but landslides never occur on level ground!

Comment: Thank you! She has not gotten back to me, but seems to have solved the issue with a tool in ArcGIS. For my part, I find the GRASS GIS solution offered more interesting and will use this for my work in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Do the cell values of the raster represent release volume or is the raster simply imagery (e.g. aerial/satellite)?  Do you have a polygon (vector) representing the slide region?

If the raster does represent volume, and you have a polygon for the slide region, then you should be able to run zonal statistics tool from ArcGIS Spatial Analyst and get the descriptive statistics for the area.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w7000000

Comment: Could you explain how this would solve the problem?  In particular, rasters rarely represent "volume": the relevant one in this case would be a DEM which, by construction, represents *height.*  Regardless, descriptive statistics would only tell you what is currently there, not what was lost during the landslide!